# How to tunnel local port through proxy server?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I have a non-proxy-aware program that I need to get working through an HTTP proxy server.  The program (MYPROG) running on a machine I can configure at will (MYSRV) connects to a specific server (DESTSRV) on a specific port (DESTPRT).  There is an existing HTTP proxy server (PROXYSRV:PROXYPRT) that will allow the traffic through if MYPROG was proxy-aware, but it isn't.

Is there a way to listen locally on a specific port and forward the traffic through the proxy server?  I can totally configure where MYPROG points to, so I could point it to MYSRV:4545 with the thought that some wonder program will redirect the data to DESTSRV:DESTPRT through PROXYSRV:PROXYPRT.  I'm thinking IP Tables or netcat could do the trick if only I could figure them out...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In terms of a port-forwarder, I'd probably employ `socat` for this, to use your example variables, it'd look something like:

```
socat tcp-listen:4545,fork,reuseaddr proxy:PROXYSRV:DESTSRV:DESTPRT,proxyport=PROXYPRT
```

And `man socat` would of course fill in any details I've forgotten.

Answer (score -1):

A port-forwarder may do the trick.